# Why linq Select request working so long? .net

Tags: c#, database, linq, request

This is a request to database which select nickname from table, if entering nickname equals nickname from table. But it works to long(near 1 min), despite that table have a few rows of data. Is it exist another faster way?

```
public string AddUser(User user)
{
    string nickname = context.Users
            .Where(a => a.Nickname == user.Nickname)
            .Select(a => a.Nickname)
            .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Edit:
Connection string(App.config):

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add connectionString="data source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=DrawDB;Integrated Security=True" name="DrawDB_cs"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

User:

```
 public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool isOnline { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
 public class DrawContext : DbContext
    {
        public DrawContext() : base("name=DrawDB_cs")
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: do you have an index on the column?

Comment: Do you have index on the `Nickname` field in the database? How many entries there are in the db? Where db is located compared to the client where the code in question runs?

Comment: Have you tried to see and execute generated SQL via some other tool(depends on db you are using)?

Comment: so you basically are looking for the `Nickname` that you already have.... Are you actually trying simply to check if the `Nickname` exists in the DB ?

Comment: do you call `AddUser` in a loop ?

Comment: I think this is not the piece of code which is creating the issue, please provide the relevant the code

Comment: The where is searching the entire table and in a large database can take time.  We need to see the connection string.  I suspect there is a no proxy server and the code is waiting 30 seconds for a response from proxy before running without proxy.

Comment: @viveknuna yea, thats 2nd column

Comment: @MongZhu yes, i'm trying to check if nickname already exist. And it isn't a loop

Comment: you can use `Any` for it: `bool exists = context.Users.Any(a => a.Nickname == user.Nickname);`

Comment: `context.Users.Any(a => a.Nickname == user.Nickname)` might be faster and returns true/false. But 60 seconds..? there has to be another problem

Comment: off-topic: `AddUser` is not adding a user, it returns a users nickname. Quite confusing ;)

Comment: @nilsK off-topic: oh, lower is checking value, and if entering nickname do not exist it adding new user with this nickname to database, but it do not matter i think